# Determining end of transaction with debezium

Tags: mysql, transactions, cdc, debezium

I'm wanting to use Debezium with kafka connect, but I need to do the work at the end of a transaction. The transaction updates many tables. I can get the GTID for each message but how do I know when I've received all messages for that transaction? I cannot start processing until I know everything is updated.

Comment: As Jiri is saying, we're planning to add support for transaction demarcation messages to Debezium in the future, but it's not there yet. What's your use case for this? Having some insight into that will help us shaping this feature. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could give me some thoughts about the use case: We have a script that runs periodically to update stock market data. We have tables for assets, price data and more. The aim is to perform calculations on the data after an update, and update delisted stocks etc. One problem is that historic price data can be amended, due to say mergers or splits, and therefore we need to know when all the price rows are finished updating before we collect the entire price history to then run some calculations on it. The reason we want to use kafka is so that we can reprocess a stock when it updates.

Comment: @Gunnar I have a similar use case that requires waiting for the end of a transaction before processing. Is there anywhere I can track the state of this feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debezium does not indicate the tx completion right now. The plan for future is to include a squence number for each change in the transaction and indicate which record is the last one. It should be then easy to aggregate the changes back to a single message.

As a stopgap solution you can use Kafka Streams session windows where session identifier will be the transaction id (GTID).

Comment: Is it still the case at the moment?